# Verify return code: 20 when testing OpenSSL

Tags: windows, wordpress, iis, openssl

I installed openSSL openssl-1.0.2e-i386-win32 on Win7 Pro 32bit with these instructions: [Installing OpenSSL in Windows 8.1](https://jchornsey.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/installing-openssl-in-windows-8-1/).

I tested it with this:

```
C:\Programs\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
```

I'm getting an error saying `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`.

```
C:\Programs\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl s_client -connect      www.openssl.org:443
CONNECTED(00000180)
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.openssl.org
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
 1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.openssl.org
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3094 bytes and written 443 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID:     2FD38B8D2C8B19A1147EF4EAE05ADCD4EEA173A4AC5DB099EC2068B8C410C447
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: DC29698D8DF1353C367B59E1A5C2ECFF701F008CB0AF065E2645F549DF3C6C2181C75EEB23528B552BD7974F6607EAC4
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 34 17 31 4f 0b 41 66 b3-72 19 aa 32 4c ab dd 2b       4.1O.Af.r..2L..+
    0010 - 75 d5 2a 39 5a 83 49 09-8b fb 9a 19 a6 8e d5 cc   u.*9Z.I.........
    0020 - 92 b6 99 2e e3 4e 7a 48-80 bc a9 ef 76 42 ac 80   .....NzH....vB..
    0030 - df 8c e2 4c 26 7a 1c 01-0f e1 6e 58 84 77 55 0c   ...L&z....nX.wU.
    0040 - b3 ce 21 ed 87 04 03 79-04 99 4d 4a 72 ac db 99   ..!....y..MJr...
    0050 - f6 d0 e2 06 f5 6c 27 f2-5b f2 5d 2a b7 be b8 cf   .....l'.[.]*....
    0060 - ec 05 18 e8 a2 ed a8 5a-8a 53 50 0f 60 dc ce 35   .......Z.SP.`..5
    0070 - c8 f6 ec 49 eb 42 46 0a-b8 82 33 28 10 63 d0 9f   ...I.BF...3(.c..
    0080 - e3 a7 00 db 23 ed c2 1a-46 06 63 58 91 88 b6 e1   ....#...F.cX....
    0090 - a2 30 93 22 31 1c b6 43-a9 a7 5e 06 bf ad 0a 99   .0."1..C..^.....
    00a0 - 84 ef 63 3f f5 eb 18 bc-88 f4 04 2f d2 4a bf 2c   ..c?......./.J.,
    00b0 - 62 ad 3e 4f 44 84 7b 87-b0 96 9e d0 19 ed 26 5d   b.>OD.{.......&]

    Start Time: 1451515804
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
read:errno=0
```

It sounded like I don't have the certificate on my machine so I went to download the certificate at:
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1464460-domainssl-intermediate-certificates

I selected SHA-256 Orders (Default)
I got a message saying:
"This certificate is already installed as a certificate authority"

So I ran a test with this:

```
 C:\Programs\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl s_client -CAfile GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
unknown option Domain
usage: s_client args

 -host host     - use -connect instead
 -port port     - use -connect instead
 -connect host:port - who to connect to (default is localhost:4433)
 -verify_host host - check peer certificate matches "host"
 -verify_email email - check peer certificate matches "email"
 -verify_ip ipaddr - check peer certificate matches "ipaddr"
 -verify arg   - turn on peer certificate verification
 -verify_return_error - return verification errors
 -cert arg     - certificate file to use, PEM format assumed
 -certform arg - certificate format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -key arg      - Private key file to use, in cert file if
                 not specified but cert file is.
 -keyform arg  - key format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -pass arg     - private key file pass phrase source
 -CApath arg   - PEM format directory of CA's
 -CAfile arg   - PEM format file of CA's
 -no_alt_chains - only ever use the first certificate chain found
 -reconnect    - Drop and re-make the connection with the same Session-ID
 -pause        - sleep(1) after each read(2) and write(2) system call
 -prexit       - print session information even on connection failure
 -showcerts    - show all certificates in the chain
 -debug        - extra output
 -msg          - Show protocol messages
 -nbio_test    - more ssl protocol testing
 -state        - print the 'ssl' states
 -nbio         - Run with non-blocking IO
 -crlf         - convert LF from terminal into CRLF
 -quiet        - no s_client output
 -ign_eof      - ignore input eof (default when -quiet)
 -no_ign_eof   - don't ignore input eof
 -psk_identity arg - PSK identity
 -psk arg      - PSK in hex (without 0x)
 -srpuser user     - SRP authentification for 'user'
 -srppass arg      - password for 'user'
 -srp_lateuser     - SRP username into second ClientHello message
 -srp_moregroups   - Tolerate other than the known g N values.
 -srp_strength int - minimal length in bits for N (default 1024).
 -ssl2         - just use SSLv2
 -ssl3         - just use SSLv3
 -tls1_2       - just use TLSv1.2
 -tls1_1       - just use TLSv1.1
 -tls1         - just use TLSv1
 -dtls1        - just use DTLSv1
 -fallback_scsv - send TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV
 -mtu          - set the link layer MTU
 -no_tls1_2/-no_tls1_1/-no_tls1/-no_ssl3/-no_ssl2 - turn off that     protocol
 -bugs         - Switch on all SSL implementation bug workarounds
 -serverpref   - Use server's cipher preferences (only SSLv2)
 -cipher       - preferred cipher to use, use the 'openssl ciphers'
                 command to see what is available
 -starttls prot - use the STARTTLS command before starting TLS
                 for those protocols that support it, where
                 'prot' defines which one to assume.  Currently,
                 only "smtp", "pop3", "imap", "ftp" and "xmpp"
                 are supported.
 -engine id    - Initialise and use the specified engine
 -rand file;file;...
 -sess_out arg - file to write SSL session to
 -sess_in arg  - file to read SSL session from
 -servername host  - Set TLS extension servername in ClientHello
 -tlsextdebug      - hex dump of all TLS extensions received
 -status           - request certificate status from server
 -no_ticket        - disable use of RFC4507bis session tickets
 -serverinfo types - send empty ClientHello extensions (comma-separated     numbers)
 -curves arg       - Elliptic curves to advertise (colon-separated list)
 -sigalgs arg      - Signature algorithms to support (colon-separated     list)
 -client_sigalgs arg - Signature algorithms to support for client
                       certificate authentication (colon-separated list)
 -nextprotoneg arg - enable NPN extension, considering named protocols supported (comma-separated list)
 -alpn arg         - enable ALPN extension, considering named protocols supported (comma-separated list)
 -legacy_renegotiation - enable use of legacy renegotiation (dangerous)
 -use_srtp profiles - Offer SRTP key management with a colon-separated profile list
 -keymatexport label   - Export keying material using label
 -keymatexportlen len  - Export len bytes of keying material (default 20)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: This is about development.  Please leave this for other people to solve the same problem.  There are many people struggling to get this answer.  Thank you,  Docfxit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first error is - you need a certificate file. Or at least path to them, so that you can verify the OpenSSL.org certificate.

Your second error - you don't specify a file and `-CAfile` requires a single certificate (PEM or DER encoded).

The easiest way to perform connection with OpenSSL.org:

Download mozilla certificate bundle from here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Run `openssl s_client -connect www.openssl.org:443 -CAfile .\cabundle.crt` and you should have a nice return code 0.

Comment: and it doesn't work how, right now?

Comment: This is what I got .                                                                                                            D:\Dnload\%WebServerSoftware>openssl s_client -connect www.openssl.org:443 -CAfile .\cabundle.crt
9584:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:175:fopen('.\cabundle.crt','r')
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate    Of course there is more but it wouldn't fit here.   I'm running windows.  Can I change it to windows?  Thank you very much, Docfxit

Comment: I did a search on my system for this file: bss_file.c   I couldn't find it.

Comment: `.\cabundle.crt` is just an example. Download the file and give a path to your downloaded certficate bundle, for example `C:\somecerts.crt`. Or just run the command from inside the directory in which your certificates are located.

Comment: You are brilliant.  I did a search for *.CRT and found lots of files called ca-bundle.crt   I ran: openssl s_client -connect www.openssl.org:443 -CAfile .\ca-bundle.crt   and it worked great. Verify return code: 0 (ok) Thank you very very much.  Docfxit

Comment: I discovered the file I downloaded from the site is ca-bundle.crt.  I ran it with this cmd line and it worked also.  C:\>openssl s_client -connect www.openssl.org:443 -CAfile D:\Dnload\%WebServerSoftware\ca-bundle.crt  Thanks,  Docfxit

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your further projects.

Comment: Sorry for the necro, but this answer helped me find the final certificate for my PEM chain that has been giving me a headache for the last few days. Got it from the Mozilla bundle, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that my OpenSSL adventures from the past are still helping people. :)